# How to make a value of <h:outputText> bold?

Tags: jsf

I have the following code:

```
<h:outputText id="dateVal" value="#{items.date}">  
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MMM-yy" />    
</h:outputText>
```

How can I display the value `#{items.date}` in bold?

Comment: It might be handy to say what you are using. And also it might be very handy to explain your situation alot better.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just do:

```
<h:outputText value="AAAAA" style="font-weight:bold"/>
```

and this code will output the following html:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">AAAAA</span>
```

Comment: ..and to learn more about this phenomenon called "CSS", start here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp :)

Comment: A phenomenon, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

How about enclosing it in a span to make it bold or adding a css style and applying it.

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">My Value Bold!</span>
```

or rather

```
<h:outputText value="AAAAAAA" style="font-weight:bold" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use **styleClass** rather than style for easier change and maintenance

```
 <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Label_place}" styleClass="recordLabel"/>
```

with a style defined in a shared style sheet you can use everywhere

```
.recordLabel {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```